# Javascript ClassName for passing the current date in the html

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code, and it works with GetElementsbyId but how can i do such so I can have GetElementsByClassName so I can pass it to more than one place in side the code, here is my code;

http://jsfiddle.net/C6Qgf/

Here is the js

```
var currentTime = new Date()
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var day = currentTime.getDate()
var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
document.write(month + "/" + day + "/" + year)
document.getElementsByClassName("time").innerHTML=(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);​
```

I would like to be able to use the Current date more than On place in my HtmL page . Thank you

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I don't understand what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @yogi sorry I have changed that

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I want to be able to use current time in many different places, if I use getElementsById("time") i can only use it in one place in page, but I want to make it as a class or something so I can use the same time as many places as I want to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged `jQuery` in your question and I'm assume you use `jQuery`

**Using jQuery**, you can do,

```
var currentTime = new Date()
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var day = currentTime.getDate()
var year = currentTime.getFullYear()

$(".time").text(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);​​​​
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/C6Qgf/3/

**Note:** If you are using native JavaScript, remember `document.getElementsByClassName` will not work on IE. There is a workaround to fix, see the below code.

**Using native JS** (with IE support)

```
var currentTime = new Date()
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var day = currentTime.getDate()
var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
//document.write(month + "/" + day + "/" + year)
var obj = getElementsByClassName("time");
for(var i=0; i<obj.length; i++){
    obj[i].innerHTML=(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
}

//For IE Fix
function getElementsByClassName(className) {
    if (document.getElementsByClassName){
      return document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    }else{
        return document.querySelectorAll('.' + className);
    }
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/C6Qgf/6/

Comment: You can use jQuery to select all elements of a certain class, but I do not see the jQuery tag in the OP's question.

Comment: @TravisJ looks like OP removed the `jQuery` tag

Comment: OH so if i make it in jquery I dont need to create an array anymore thank you

Comment: I didnt know if I use jquery its much faster and easier, thank you for teaching me that

Comment: @behzad_b Updated my answer without using jQuery.

Comment: With the jquery do you need to make one for IE, because I noticed that IE Fix.

Comment: if you are using jQuery solution, IE fix is not required.

Answer (score 1):

You are retrieving an array, so you need to loop trough it. also, do not use `document.write` as it replaces the document content.

You also missed all your semicolons, this can lead to unexpected results in certain situations, so remember to always add them.

Here is the updated example:

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
var day = currentTime.getDate();
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
var cls = document.getElementsByClassName('time');

for (var i = 0; i < cls.length; i++) {
    cls[i].innerHTML = (month + "/" + day + "/" + year);​​​​
}
```

**fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/C6Qgf/1/